# how to convert two array value in JSON format

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, cookies

my controller

```
 public function showcart()
{

    $da = isset($_COOKIE["cart"]) ? $_COOKIE["cart"] : "[]";

    $data = json_decode($da);
    
    return view('customer.showcart', compact('data'));
}
```

blade:

```
<tbody>
                @foreach ($data as $dat)
                    <form action="{{ url('/addcart') }}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $dat['id'] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $dat['quantity']}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </form>
                @endforeach

            </tbody>
```

current output

```
{"id":["8","8","8","9","9","8","8","8","10"],"quantity":["3","2","3","3","2","1","2","1","6"]}
```

I want to convert this in JSON with each of the indexes like id[0] with quantity[0], id[1] with quantity [1].

Comment: Try `json_decode($da, true)` and why do you need `compact`. `$data` is already an array

Comment: What is the expected result? Can you provide that in PHP format for this example data?

Comment: ''Attempt to read property "id" on array'' if I use '''json_decode($da, true)''' this.

Comment: `{"8":3,"8":2,"8":3}` like this.

Comment: An object cannot have duplicate keys, so that is not valid JSON. Well, theoretically it is, but it is equal to just `{"8": 3}`, ignoring duplicates.

Comment: yeah I know, it was just a testing result actually. I just need the algorithm. :)

Comment: Please update the example in your question then, so it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aimed for key/value pairs, then please be aware that an object cannot have duplicate keys, and since your `id` values are 8, 9, or 10 (in the example), the output could not have more than 3 keys:

```
{"8": 1, "9": 2, "10": 6}
```

Anyway, if your keys are indeed unique in reality, then you need `array_combine`:

```
$arr = json_decode($da, true);
$data = array_combine($arr["id"], $arr["quantity"]);
```

Note that your assignment to `$da` needs a different default case to make it compatible:

```
$da = isset($_COOKIE["cart"]) ? $_COOKIE["cart"] : '{"id":[],"quantity":[]}';
```

Finally, your loop should extract the key and value differently:

```
<form action="{{ url('/addcart') }}" method="post">
    @csrf 
    <table>
    @foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $key }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: `array_combine(): Argument #1 ($keys) must be of type array, string given`

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. See it run on [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/HPhRk#v7.4.23). Something must be different from what you told us.

Comment: Please provide the *exact* value you have for `$_COOKIE["cart"]`, so your problem is reproducible.

Comment: checking. i will let you know brother. :)

Comment: hi! when i am using dd to see the values it is showing good. like `array:3 [▼
  8 => "3"
  9 => "4"
  10 => "4"
]` but when i am trying to pass the data to blade it's saying `Attempt to read property "id" on string` this.

Comment: Just provide the exact value of `$_COOKIE["cart"]`. As you see in the link I provided, it works with the JSON string you provided, so it must be that `$_COOKIE["cart"]` is different, or you didn't use the exact code I provided.

Comment: i used your code but problem is not in controller. it is in blade.

 ` <tbody>
                    @foreach ($data as $dat)
                        <form action="{{ url('/addcart') }}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $dat->id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $dat->quantity }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </form>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>`

Comment: Added a section to my answer about that form-code.

Comment: do you know how can i call all the key of the array?

Comment: You mean [`array_keys`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)?

Comment: yes i want to change a value of the array. like if `array:3 [▼   8 => "3"   9 => "4"   10 => "4" ]` this is the array, and i want to change the element 1 value only. like this `array:3 [▼   8 => "3"   9 => "5"   10 => "4" ]`

Comment: Just make the modification with `$data["9"] = 5;`

Comment: is there anything else i can use without array combine . because sometime my system will have single element array. that's where currently error is showing. is there anyway to overcome this problem?